# Yii - Add title in URL.

Tags: php, url, yii

This is my site url is `http://sitename/search?city=1` and i want to add title in this url.
it should be like `http://sitename/search?city=1/title` or `http://sitename/title/search?city=1`

so i tried something like this,

```
array(
  'search/<title>'=>'search',
  '<title>/search'=>'search',
)
```

both are not working, whether it is achievable, if so how to achieve this?

Comment: `http://sitename/search?city=1/title` will not work. What is with `http://sitename/search?city=1&title=title`? ir do you want it in path format?

Comment: link should be readable and it convey some message and something like this sitename/<title>/search?city=1 and i wont process anything using title, so no need of this &title=title...

Comment: Do you used url rules befor you tryied this? if yes, can you please add them

Comment: 'rules'=>array(
                                'property/<id:\d+>/<title>'=>'site/viewPublic',) i tried this and it works but in this case search?city=1/title not working...

Comment: I will shortly build a new Yii application for me and if i found a solution i will inform you

Comment: An other question, is the controller name not a title enough?

Comment: actually i am doing real estate website, i want my user to know which page they are visiting, like http://sitename/appartments-in-cityname/search?city=1. Thanks for your response @Dinistro

Comment: And where is the controller in your link?

Comment: i rewrite url like this 'search'=>'site/search', site is my controller..

Answer (score 0):

I finaly found a solution:

```
array(
  '<action:\w+>/<title>/'=>'site/<action>'
)
```

if you had this in your `rules` you can create an url like this:

```
Yii::app()->createUrl("site/index", array('title' => 'test'));
```